# Redirect requests to a directory that do NOT match a pattern

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have the following URLs

```
1) domain.com/articles/one-two-three
2) domain.com/articles/four-five-six
3) domain.com/articles/{name of a post}
4) domain.com/articles/wp-content/
5) domain.com/articles/wp-admin/
```

I want to redirect URL 1, 2 and 3, but not 4 and 5. In other words I want to redirect all pages in the `/articles/` directory that do not start with `wp-`

This following snippet will redirect EVERYTHING that comes after `/articles/`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
# RedirectMatch 301 /articles/(.*) http://domain.com/$1
```

How do I filter this Redirect match to exclude a pattern?

**Edit** In response to some of the comments

What is the input URL (from the browser) you are testing with,

```
http://www.chipkin.com/articles/steam-boilers-vs-hydronic-boilers/
```

What is the expected output?

```
http://www.chipkin.com/steam-boilers-vs-hydronic-boilers/
```

And since this appears to be WordPress, Post any other rules you may already have a in the .htaccess, as there could be conflicts.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the request doesn't start /articles/wp-
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/articles/wp-
# Rewrite it:
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*) http://www.chipkin.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a `RedirectMatch`, use a `RewriteCond` to verify that the URI doesn't begin with `/articles/wp-` and perform the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the request doesn't start /articles/wp-
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/articles/wp-
# Rewrite it:
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have tried a this and a few variants of this snippet without success. I have simplified your snippet to just have the RewriteRule but I can't seem to get that working either.

Comment: @Stevensmethurst What is the input URL (from the browser) you are testing with, and what is the expected output?  And since this appears to be WordPress, Post any other rules you may already have a in the .htaccess, as there could be conflicts.

Comment: I have updated the original question with responses to your questions.

Comment: @Stevensmethurst Is this in a .htaccess file or in the server config? If it is in the server config, you would need to have a leading `/` in `RewriteRule` as in `RewriteRule ^/articles...`

Comment: And if this is a .htaccess, does the file live at the site's document root?

Comment: @Stevensmethurst This could be the result of the browser caching redirects. Never test with `301` enabled! Always use `302` and switch to `301` only, if everything works as it should.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that there was a .httaccess in the /articles/ folder as well. Thank you for your help!